# Can an Akka Stream be Distributed to the Front End?

Tags: stream, streaming, akka, distributed, actor

Is it possible to have an Akka Stream that goes from the front-end to the back-end in a multi-tenant SaaS application? 
I know you can distribute Actors this way. But I've never heard of it being done with Streams

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the project https://github.com/unicredit/akka.js . It is the porting of akka on the browser.